# How to force wget to not URL-encode?

Tags: wget, url-encoding

This seems like it should be simple, but I'm having trouble figuring it out. I want to send a `wget` request similar to the following,

```
wget http://www.foo.com/bar.cgi?param=\"p\"
```

but I don't want it to URL-encode the quotes (or anything else, for that matter). Is this possible?

And just to make it clear, I am a) dealing with a server that doesn't URL-decode -- nothing I can do about that -- and b) aware that I can do this with a Python script, or Burp, or many other things. I just need to know if `wget` can do it.

Thanks!

Comment: could you find any solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So `curl` does not automatically URL-encode parameters in a GET request. This doesn't totally answer my question, but it does give me another option. This:

```
curl 'http://www.foo.com/bar.cgi?param="p"'
```

does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the URL in single quotes. This works also for URLs with ampersands and exclamation marks (!).

Comment: The single quotes eliminate the need for forward slashes, but they were never an issue. Even enclosed in single quotes, the double quotes are still URL-encoded by wget

Answer (score 0):

I am running into the same issue, and already have working code in `wget` that I'd prefer to keep that way. There is some documentation on the `wget` website about providing some control over these parameters using `--restrict-file-names=modes`

https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#URL-Format

Comment: This has nothing to do with the encoding of the URL sent to the server, it only affects the file name generation to store the response.

Comment: incorrect answer. it's official description: `Change which characters found in remote URLs must be escaped during generation of local filenames...`